# GWT 2.4 Updated MVP sample

Tags: gwt, mvp, uibinder

I'm looking for a project sample of the latest GWT 2.4 version using MVP and UIBinder.
All the samples i could find, are really old, and most of the functions and classes are deprecated.

The latest sample I found is [Contacts](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) from GWT site, that is from March 2010.

Where can I find the most relevant and updated GWT MVP + UIBinder project sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Expenses](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/expenses/) and [MobileWebapp](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/) samples from the GWT SDK.

Answer (score 0):

this is one has perfect explanation of what you want and source code 
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces?hl=de-DE